# HttpClient not returning API data that matches my model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Hi wrote a little web app that connects to an API.

It is connecting to the API and returning data as you can see here:

```
 astroTechItem= await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<AstroTechItem[]>("api/AstroTechItem/34");
```

And it's returning the following JSON:

```
{
"objectId": 34,
"scopeId": 3,
"title": "solar telescope",
"completed": false
```

}

In my app, I have this model:

```
private class AstroTechItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}
```

And I am deserializing like this:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

try
{
    return serializer.Deserialize<AstroTechItem>(jsonReader);
}
catch(JsonReaderException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid JSON.");
} 
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("HTTP Response was invalid and cannot be deserialised.");
}
```

But my model does not match what the API is returning.

My console keeps showing: `Invalid JSON.`

Do I need to contact the maker of the API and have them change it?

Or is there a way to fit that JSON into my model?

I can't figure it out.

thanks!

Comment: Which JSON serialization library do you use? There must be member annotation attributes allowing to define json property names. For example for Newtonsoft json.net there is `[JsonProperty("json_name")]`, for `Text.Serialization.Json` there is `[JsonPropertyName("json_name"])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deserialize json to a model, the model's properties must match the properties of the json. Or you can annotate the model with the json property names. In your case none of the properties match.

Easiest is to update the model to align it with the external API like so:

```
private class AstroTechItem
{
  public long ObjectId { get; set; }
  public long ScopeId { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public bool Completed { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise you can annotate the model:

```
private class AstroTechItem
{
  [JsonProperty("objectId")]
  public long Id { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("title")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("isComplete")]
  public bool Completed { get; set; }
}
```